# Proof for Convergent Sequences

Tags: analysis, proof-writing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Did I underestimate the limit proof?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/200939/did-i-underestimate-the-limit-proof)

Let $(a)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ and $(b)_{n\in \Bbb N}$ be sequences of real numbers such that $a_n$ $\le$ $b_n$ for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Prove that if $a_n \to a$ and $b_n \to b$;
then a $\le$ b.

I have this question as homework. I have some sort of solution in mind but the professor wants us to hand in a formal proof. What I thought so far is to assume contrary, that a $\gt$ b, and to examine $n$ for large numbers to conclude $b_n \gt a_n$ and to have contradiction. But my problem is I don't even know what formal proof is. Could you please tell me what it is using this question.

Comment: Consider the sequence $b_n - a_n$.  What does this converge to?

Comment: b - a. Where does this lead me to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume by contradiction that $a >b$.

Let $\epsilon >0$, we will pick it later.

Then there exists an $N$ so that for all $n> N$ we have

$$|a_n -a| < \epsilon \Rightarrow  a_n > a- \epsilon$$

$$|b_n -b| < \epsilon \Rightarrow  b_n < b+\epsilon $$

Now, if you pick some $\epsilon$ so that $b+ \epsilon \leq a-\epsilon$ you get

$$ b_n < b+ \epsilon \leq a-\epsilon < a_n \,,$$

contradictions...

You  figure now the right $\epsilon$, and start your argument by "Let $\epsilon= ...$.

Comment: The correct $\epsilon$ is $a-b$ to get: $b_n < a \leq b < a_n$ ?

Comment: I suppose $a - b$ can be used for the conradiction. Is it what you have in mind @n-s ?

Comment: @MertToka $b+\epsilon \leq a- \epsilon$ means $2\epsilon \leq a-b$... So nope $\epsilon = a-b$ won't work, but figuring one so that $2 \epsilon \leq a-b$ should be really easy....